# How to position a div at the bottom of the viewport in standard and in quirks mode?

Tags: javascript, position, doctype, fixed

I need to position a div to the bottom of my viewport. 
I start using position:fixed; bottom:0px; and that work just fine.
But the thing that I'm working on gets injected via javascript in different pages. And some of the pages doesn't have a doctype defined, so in IE gets rendered like quircks mode, so the div doesn't get positioned correctly..
I've tried to position the div using javascript (document.documentElement.clientHeight) and that works fine. But when no doctype is defined, the "document.documentElement.clientHeight" is 0, so again the div doesn't get positioned correctly.
Any idea on how to fix this problem?
I'm only interested in IE 7 and 8.

Thanks in advance
Gonzalo

Comment: seems to me the easiest solution is make sure all your pages have a doc type.   this'll avoid other potential problems as well.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot dynamically add a Doctype declaration VIA javascript... document object owns HTML node, so if you created a doctype, you'd append it to document.  However, you can't create a Doctype afaik...  Note that Doctype isn't an element, it's an instruction to the browser

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with the comments stating that you should better ensure that every page is served with a (valid) doctype that triggers standards mode (and you can't change this nor the rendering mode on-the-fly), you can test whether you're in standards mode or in quirks mode using [`document.compatMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533687%28VS.85%29.aspx). This property returns either `CSS1Compat` when using the former or `BackCompat` when using the latter.

In standards mode, you can just use a `<div>` with `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` (in IE 7 and 8). When using quirks mode, you'll have to use an absolutely positioned `<div>` above an absolutely positioned viewport `<div>` (where `<body>` and `<html>` have a `height` of `100%`). I'm too tired now to write a full example, but you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857412/ie6-frame-layout-with-100-height-and-scrollbars/2858341#2858341) to see how this can be done. Note that in IE's quirks mode `document.body.clientHeight` returns the height of the viewport (also see [Finding the size of the browser window](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow)).