# keeping a DIV at the top and center of the page with ability change size div

Tags: javascript, css

keeping a DIV at the top and center of the page with ability change size div like loading box in Gmail?

Comment: Your question is extremely hazy. Please add more detail. Not everybody knows GMail, and which part of GMail you mean exactly.

Comment: Just one important thing. Use CSS as Pekka sais, do not use Javascript for this sort of things.

Answer (score 2):

As I said, your question is extremely hazy but I guess you are looking to place a DIV at a fixed position that stays there even when the page is scrolled.

The CSS way to do this is

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;">....</div>
```

won't work in IE < 7. The only way to make this work in IE6, as far as I know, is kludgy and jittery JavaScript-based workarounds.

Comment: +1 - These are the kinds of things we were able to greatly simplify after getting the go ahead to slap a "IE6 won't work here" on the front page :)

Comment: There is some trick doing this in IE6 without JS, but you really don't want to mess up your hole CSS just to have that effect in IE6.

Comment: It's not that difficult in IE6, you can put the all contents in a `<div>` with 100% height and width and put the box at the top in another `<div>`; see [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857412/ie6-frame-layout-with-100-height-and-scrollbars/2858341#2858341).

Comment: @Marcel - We have a watermark logo in the background, which complicates things in IE6 with your code...fortunately I don't have to spend any more time figuring out how to make something work in IE6.  It's a tremendous resource drain; your solution involves changing my layout for everyone else to suit IE6, which is 100% the wrong direction in my case. I was able to simplify so much of our layout when removing the elements/structure specifically there to support IE6 it's ridiculous.